# How are filled paths rendered?

Tags: algorithm, vector-graphics

What are the standard algorithms used in vector graphics for rendering filled paths?

I'm not only interested in the process of rendering strokes, I also would like to know how the shapes are filled - how it is determined if given point is inside or outside the path (I believe even specifying the rules of what inside and outside mean is not a straightforward thing).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851700/vector-graphics-flood-fill-algorithms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **find outline (perimeter as polygon)**

   this I think you already have
2. **triangulate (or cut to convex polygons)**

   there are many approaches like:

   - clip ear
   - Delaunay

   see [Wiki Polygon triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation)
3. **fill convex triangles/polygons**

   this is easy either use

   - gfx lib like OpenGL,DirectX,...
   - api like GDI
   - rasterize on your own like in [how to rasterize convex polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19078088/2521214)
4. **style**

   This stuff is more complicated then it sound like at the first hear. For:

   1. **outline width** `pen,stroke`

      convert outline to polygon by shifting it out or in. For more info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22068534/2521214)
   2. **outline style** `pen,stroke`

      full,dash dot,dot dot,...  for more info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18643561/2521214)
   3. **filling style** `brush`

      like hatching which is most complicated from all. It involves heavy polygon tweaking similar but much harder then **outline width**. Some styles are simpler some extremly complicated for example for equidistant line fill simple `loop + intersection + inside polygon test will` do. To test polygon inside you can use [hit test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24465094/2521214)

Comment: But paths can also contain curves and it's a lot more complex with them.

Comment: @mrpyo yes and no usually bezier cubics are used which are simple polynomials. you have to handle them as many smaller lines or as curve while cutting down to convex shapes. which one depends on the rasterisation device and methods used. If you want to use different curves you should specify them ...